# Notification framework for java

Tags: java, email, sms, messaging, notifications

I'm in the process of developing a web application (java + jsp) that can send notifications to users.  The user can subscribe to multiple events generated by the application and can choose to receive the messages associated with those events via multiple channels (email, sms, growl?, messenger); perhaps different messages through different channels; perhaps a daily message digest.  Everything must be configurable by the user.  Is there some framework that deals with this?

Answer (score 3):

Rmarimon, check out [Boomerang Notification Framework](http://www.fuel9.com/wp/notification-framework/) from Fuel9. With some basic SQL skills you can quickly develop dynamic notifications (email, twitter, fax etc). Good luck!

/M

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Amazon Simple Notification Service](http://aws.amazon.com/sns/) (Amazon SNS).  It was just released (in beta).  Looks pretty cool.

Comment: Will look into this more closely but it looks promising.

Answer (score 0):

[Agustin](http://blog.pomelollc.com/twitter-email-and-sms-integration-all-for-the) sends to email and SMS via twitter. Probably not exactly what you're after, but it might work.

There's also the [Sun Java System Instant Messaging](http://www.sun.com/software/products/instant_messaging/faq_stub.xml), which is not free.